# freeze(account, balance) for pallet-assets, how do I freeze X amount of a certain asset?

Tags: pallet, balances, assets, lockable-currency

Does anyone know if there is a way to freeze (pallet-)asset's similar to how you can "lock"/freeze regular balance with T::Currency::freeze(AccountId, Balance)?

seems like there is no easy way to freeze 10 of asset X for account Y,  the default freeze functions only freezes the entire account balance or entire asset class

The use case that I have one pallet that mints X amount of a certain asset(like a token) then transfers it using the regular pallet-asset's transfer assetid, amount(T::Balance).

But all built in pallet-assets freeze functions is created for freezing the entire asset class. is there some way around this?

Link to pallet-assets:
https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_assets/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible but it is in the roadmap to add lockable assets the way that you described (which also enables other things like vesting). The high level tokens roadmap is here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/8453